# How to align brackets in this diagram?

Tags: vertical-alignment, xy-pic

When I write the following :

```
\documentclass[psamsfonts]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[all,arc]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[Q(M) :=\left[
 \xymatrix{
  &\Xi(j^*M) \ar@{->>}[rd]^{can}\\
  j_!j^*M \ar@{^{(}->}[ru]^{can} \ar[rd]_{can}
  & 
  & j_*j^* M \\
  & M \ar[ru]_{can}
 }
\right] \]
\end{document}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

I ended up getting Q(M) aligned to the first line of `\xymatrix{}`, and a huge empty space is inserted to the top of the content of `\xymatrix{}` in order to make Q(M) aligned to the middle of the bracket. This is ugly.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please complete your example to make it compilable. It should start with `\documentclass{` and end with `\end{document}`

Comment: made my answer before your real MWE came. Let me know, if you run in incompatibilities. Please always provide MWEs so that helpers do not need to guess around. Happy TeXing to you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[Q(M) :=\left[
\!\begin{gathered}
 \xymatrix{
  & \Xi(j^*M) \ar@{->>}[rd]^{can} & \\
  j_!j^*M \ar@{^{(}->}[ru]^{can} \ar[rd]_{can} &  & j_*j^* M \\
 & M \ar[ru]_{can} &
 }
\end{gathered}
\right] \]
\end{document}
```

[image]